# $R^2$ in Linear Regression

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, predictive-models, r-squared

I am facing some weird issue on calculating $R^2$. Probably, I am messing it up somewhere badly.

I am applying a LR model like this:

```
linmodel = lm(helpfulness~., data = train)
summary(linmodel)
```

The summary of this model gives me an $R^2$ = 0.1948

I am now trying to check this $R^2$ value by using the "predict" function on the same dataset I used for training:

```
pred = predict(linmodel, newdata =train, interval ="predict")
Rsquared=1- sum((pred-train$helpfulness)^2)/sum((train$helpfulness-mean(train$helpfulness))^2)
```

By using the formula above for $R^2$, I am getting -7.724273

My question is : Should I not be getting same $R^2$ as the summary of the model trained on the given training data gives.

My logic is that I am training a model on a dataset and then I apply the model developed on the same training dataset, I should be getting same fit and same $R^2$

Comment: It would be a very good idea to read the manual page for `predict.lm` so you can know what your call to `predict` actually is returning.  You are asking for the limits of a prediction interval, not for a prediction, and that will become abundantly clear if you would inspect `pred`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know if this question fits here, since the question is only r-related.

however: the prediction function with the option "interval ="predict"" results in a $n\times3$ matrix: the first column contains the fitted values (which you could obtain via fitted(linmodel)) the other two columns give you a confidence intervall.
this implies that you have to change

```
Rsquared=1- sum((pred-train$helpfulness)^2)/sum((train$helpfulness-mean(train$helpfulness))^2)
```

to

```
Rsquared=1- sum((pred[,1]-train$helpfulness)^2)/sum((train$helpfulness-mean(train$helpfulness))^2)
```

in order to get meaningful results.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir! It is R-related only when you know where the problem is. For me, I had started doubting my fundamentals by missing the coding part of it. It might definitely help some other novice like me who might go through similar thing and visit cross-validated.:)